# fgets not receiving right user input

Tags: fgets

I've been working on some code to take in a user input of up to 80 characters and output the characters in reverse. I'm trying to use fgets to accept the user input and then from there I will print out the array in reverse order.

This is the code i have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char i[80];

    printf("Input:\n");
    fgets(i, 80, stdin);

    printf("%c", i);
}
```

The output:

```
Ð
```

I also tried some other code from online that worked:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
  char name[10];
  printf("Who are you? ");
  fgets(name,10,stdin);
  printf("Glad to meet you, %s.n",name);
  return(0);
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and would appreciate any help.

After fixing my code it now looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char i[80];

    printf("Input:\n");
    fgets(i, 80, stdin);

    printf("%s\n", i);

    printf("%s\n", i[0]);
}
```

When I input "qwerty" into the console, the line shifts down but the program does not run, and then it eventually terminates.

Comment: You can't use the %c format for strings - use %so instead, like in the code that works.

Comment: That works but now I'm not able to print an individual element of the array

Comment: So, you need to learn about [array indexing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm).

Comment: I believe I'm already doing that properly. I updated the original post to show my new code, but my problem is now that the console doesn't accept the input and will just terminate. This only happens when I try to print an individual element, but not when I print the entire array.

Comment: For the whole array (`s`) use `%s`. For a single element (`s[0]`) use `%c`.

Comment: That works thanks alot.